# How to create an instances from all classes that implement generic interface that inherite from another generic Interface with reflection in C# a

Tags: c#, reflection

Using C#, how do I create instances of classes that implement a generic interface, that inherits from another generic interface using Reflection.
I need to get the implementation of BarcodeTestHelper and BarcodeRepository and create instances of them.

My model:

```
public interface ITestData{}
public class BarcodelData : ITestData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My API:

```
public interface IBaseTestHelper<T> where T : ITestData {}
public interface IBarcodeTestHelper : IBaseTestHelper<BarcodeTestData>
```

My implementation:

```
public class BarcodeTestHelper : TestBaseHelper, IBarcodeTestHelper
{
    private readonly IBarcodeRepository<BarcodeTestData> _barcodeRepository;
    public BarcodeTestHelper(IBarcodeRepository<BarcodeTestData>                                           barcodeRepository) 
    {
        _barcodeRepository = barcodeRepository;
    }
 }

public interface IBarcodeRepository<T> : IRepository<BarcodeTestData> where T : ITestData
{
    BarcodeTestData SaveBarcode(string xmlBarcode);
}

public class BarcodeRepository :  IBarcodeRepository<BarcodeTestData>
{
    BarcodeTestData SaveBarcode(string xmlBarcode)
    {
        do save work
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing and sorry for the misspelling.